# Javascript form filter based on json or XML to make option boxes

Tags: javascript, json, filter

I am trying to think up a filter method based on AJAX, XML or Json. I would like to hear from anyone who has either made such a filter or have any tips.

The data could be:

```
<wine table>
<wine>
<color>red</color>
<origin>California</origin>
<produced>2005</produced>
<grape>Pinot Noir</grape>
</wine>

<wine>
<color>white</color>
<origin>France</origin>
<produced>2008</produced>
<grape>Chardonnay</grape>
</wine>
</wine table>
```

Must be able to:

1. Create form fields to select subgroups
2. When user selects first selection, all the subgroups must alter to correct data below. (filter the option boxes to match resulting filter data)
3. If user start the selected on form field ie 3 (grapes), the previous option boxes must alter to correct filter data.

Does anyone know of any script or tutorial or anything that can help me?

Comment: Well I am not going to start up a 200 hours project without getting some input. I have already build a filter, but I want this one to be build the right way.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at [ExtJS examples](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/example/form/xml-form.html).

With ExtJS it's quite easy. Schematically:

- You define a `Wine` *model* with fields `color`, `origin` and so on.
- Define a *proxy* for the model (a list URLs for create/read/update/destroy) with a *reader* and *writer* of the JSON or XML type.
- Create a *view* with a form component.
- Create a `datagrid` *view* to
  browse wines and load them into the form
  (as simple as [`form.loadRecord(wineModelRecord)`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.Panel-method-loadRecord)). See [this example](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/example/form/form-grid.html).
- In controller you subscribe to the `submit` event of the form to
  create/update `Wine` model records.

Actually, I believe the same can be done easily with any other MVC framework, like Backbone.js or Angular.js.

Comment: great answer! there is some news for me here I need to investigate.